# Is there a direct way to know the points belonging to a segment $AB$ for a line in $\mathbb R^2$ given two initial coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two points $A = (x1, y1)$ and $B = (x2, y2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, is there a direct way to find out the set of coordinates that belongs to the line crossing the aforementioned two points? Particularly the ones in the segment $AB$

Elaboration.
For $A = (20, 49)$ and $B = (50, 1)$, we can derive the equation for a line: $\frac{8}{5}x + y = 81$
How can you come up with the set of coordinates belonging to this line, in the $AB$ segment without guess choosing (probably randomly) any $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ to be tested for the equation?

Thanks!

--
Caleb

Comment: After you have the equation for the line, add a condition that $a$ should be between $x_1$ and $x_2$. As in

$$\left\{\left(a, 81-\frac{8}{5}a\right)\middle| 20\le a \le 50\right\}$$

(with some adjustments if $x_1=x_2$)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I asked my question properly. By the way I am surprised by the velocity of your answer.
You are recommending adding a condition, so perhaps you have assumed I am writing a computer program, since I am a Software Developer, you may be right in your assumption, but I was in fact interested in a Mathematical method or formulae.  Because, even when your advice reduces the search space for the points to be tested in the equation, it is not a direct way (Which may doesn't exists) to come up (generate/know) the points in the segment AB. I really appreciate your answer bud!

Comment: I think my comment above would define the set of coordinates using [set-builder notation with a predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate). (Maybe also add another *condition* or predicate $a\in\mathbb R$ to be clear)

Comment: Indeed, thanks buddy!

Comment: Yeah, you did specified the answer in a correct fashion, sorry I misread the condition part. Thanks a lot peterwhy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a recipe to produce points on a line segment, a good way is to use the fact that if $P$ and $Q$ are the end points of a line segment, then the points on that segment are precisely those of the form $tP+(1-t)Q$ for some $t\in [0,1]$ (here we are treating the points like vectors, so that multiplication and addition make sense).  This "parametrization" of a line segment is quite handy.

So, in your case, you would have an alternative description of you line segment as points of the form
$$
t(20,49)+(1-t)(50,1)= (20t +50(1-t),49t+1(1-t)) = (50 - 30t,1 +48t)
$$
so your set is
$$\{(50 - 30t,1 +48t)\mid 0\le t\le 1\}\text{.}$$
If you later decide you want the whole infinite line joining the two points, rather than just the segment, the same parametrization works, you just change the values of $t$ to span the entire set of real numbers.
$$\{(50 - 30t,1 +48t)\mid -\infty<t<\infty\}\text{.}$$

This works in three or more dimensions as well, and in higher dimensions is much easier than trying to find the equations for the line and solving them.

#### Remark

I see from the comments you are coming from software engineering. You could use this parametric form to generate points on the line by taking a discrete sequence of decimals approximating $[0,1]$ (e.g., $.01,.02,\dots,.99,1$) and substituting them in for $t$ in the above formula, and that would generate points on the line.

Comment: Thank you M W!
And by the way how did you arrive to such fact:  "a good way is to use the fact that if P
 and Q
 are the end points of a line segment, then the points on that segment are precisely those of the form tP+(1−t)Q
 for some t∈[0,1]"
I was about to ask you for a book recommendation, but I have enough to read for the time being (The Gelfand series on Elementary Mathematics [Five books])
Thanks!

Comment: @calebjosue It's a pretty standard fact about linear functions - to prove it, just observe that it clearly gives you a linear expression in the variable $t$, so it definitely will be *some* line.  But when $t=0$ it gives you $Q$ and when $t=1$ it gives you $P$, so that forces it to be the line passing through those two points, as every two points uniquely determine a line.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.